# Mobile First: Aparecer imagem somente no desktop

Tags: css, mobile, aplicação-desktop

Qual a melhor forma de fazer uma imagem aparecer somente no *desktop*? Geralmente eu adiciono uma `media query` para colocar um `display: none` quando abrir no *mobile*. Porém essa imagem é processada pelo celular, só não e exibida.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso sem ter essa perda de performance?

Comment: depende do modo que você quer se for em background por css da, mas caso o contrario vai usar o source do html

Answer (score 3):

Tem como fazer usando o `srcset`. Ele só vai chamar a imagem que estiver configurada para a resolução da tela.

Aqui tem um exemplo prático. E abaixo estão os screenshots do Developer Tools.
https://codepen.io/olivier-c/pen/QNYRPG

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre essa técnica.
http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#element-attrdef-img-srcset

---

**Código do exemplo demostrado acima.**

**OBS:** Execute o *snipper* primeiro e vai carregar a imagem de 800px, depois passe para "Página toda" para ver o carregamento de uma imagem maior!

```css
body {
  margin: 1rem;
  background-color: #333;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
figure {
  max-width: 40rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background-color: LightCoral;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 2000px)" srcset="https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest.jpg, https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest.jpg 2x" sizes="100vw"/>
    <source media="(min-width: 1500px)" srcset="https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest2000.jpg, https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest.jpg 2x" sizes="100vw"/>
    <source media="(min-width: 1000px)" srcset="https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest1500.jpg, https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest2000.jpg 2x" sizes="100vw"/>
    <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest1000.jpg, https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest2000.jpg 2x" sizes="100vw"/>
    <source media="(min-width: 600px)" srcset="https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest800.jpg, https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest1500.jpg 2x" sizes="100vw"/>
    <source media="(min-width: 400px)" srcset="https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest600.jpg, https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest1000.jpg 2x" sizes="100vw"/>
    <source media="(min-width: 300px)" srcset="https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest400.jpg, https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest800.jpg 2x" sizes="100vw"/>
    <source srcset="https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest300.jpg" sizes="100vw"/><img src="https://scriptura.github.io/Images/LotusTest.jpg" alt="Lotus"/>
  </picture>
</figure>
```