# Qual o melhor modo de trabalhar com imagens responsivas?

Tags: html5, media-queries, img, picture

Estou em duvida no meu projeto qual a melhor forma de trabalhar com imagens responsivas DIRETO NO HTML, no html5 a tag  possui o atributo srcset que permite essa mudança utilizando o prefixo "w" ao selecionar a tela, mas em algumas pesquisas que realizei dizem que a tag  permitira maior facilidade nesse trabalho árduo já que ele permite utilizar as propiás medias query que se popularizou tanto no css e queria saber a opinião da comunidade sobre o assunto. E se existe alguma outra forma de realizar a responsividade das imagens de outra forma sem prejudicar o desempenho do site.

Comment: No assunto "responsividade" o [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) é campeão. Já ouviu falar?

Comment: Depende do seu projeto, pois por exemplo o srcset não é 100% compatível com todos os browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=srcset. Eu optaria por media-queries.

Comment: Jorge por favor me explica como que o Bootstrap trata o tamanho da imagem?? Vc acha que image-fluid já é suficiente?

Comment: Concordo que o bootstrap e a primeira ferramenta a se pensar em caso de responsividade, mas quando se trabalha com imagem e importante ter no minimo 2 versões dela uma para mobile e outra para pc (na verdade geralmente vejo sendo trabalho com 4 versões da mesma foto), e esse sim e o foco da minha pergunta

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Eu acredito no srcset com certeza. Primeiro que ele é mais semântico que que uma tag img mais simples, vc pode usar `<figcaption>` etc.

Depois que pelos teste que fiz ele carrega apenas a imagem pra resolução certa.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com isso vc pode manter uma qualidade maior nas imagens e não ficar usando apenas uma imagem "espichada" para qualquer resolução, mudando apenas `width` e `height` nos *@medias*, aqui vc realmente usa uma imagem diferente de forma prática!

Vc pode usar o `srcset` dessa forma por exemplo:

```
<figure>
  <picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 2000px)" srcset="suaimagem-grande.png" sizes="100vw"/>
    <source media="(min-width: 1500px)" srcset="suaimagem-pequena.png" sizes="100vw"/>
  <figure>
<picture>
```

***Veja aqui um exemplo prático e repare que quando vc exibir o Snippet em "Tela toda" a imagem vai mudar.***

```css
.item {
      background: url(http://placecage.com/600/200) no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      padding: 10px;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
  }
  picture {
      margin: auto
  }
```

```html
<figure class="item">
  <picture>
     <source srcset="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icocentre-free-icons/114/f-cross_256-128.png" media="(min-width:768px)" />
     <source srcset="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icocentre-free-icons/137/f-check_256-128.png" media="(min-width:450px)" />
     <img src="http://placecage.com/300/300" alt="imagem de fundo do banner" />    
  </picture>
</figure>
```

Aqui tem um exemplo prático. https://codepen.io/olivier-c/pen/QNYRPG

Recomendo a leitura dessa resposta [Mobile First: Aparecer imagem somente no desktop](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257945/mobile-first-aparecer-imagem-somente-no-desktop/257961#257961)

E da documentação no Git da W3C: http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-embedded-content.html#element-attrdef-img-srcset

Comment: Amiguinhos do "Down Vote" fiquem a vontade para dar uma resposta melhor! A comunidade serve para isso, para acrescentar algo aos demais. Aqui é um espaço aberto para você também contribuir! Eu ficaria feliz em saber o que posso melhorar na minha resposta ou o que está errado nela. []´s