# Carregamento das Imagens em diferentes resoluções

Tags: css, bootstrap

Quero fazer um Carousel em Bootstrap para Banners de eventos de uma igreja.
Gostaria de saber:

1) Quantos banners diferentes eu precisaria fazer para atender a todas as resoluções, satisfatoriamente?

2) Se eu carregar as imagens e usar tags como `.visible-phone`, `.visible-desktop`, etc, os navegadores CARREGARÃO todas as imagens que estiverem presentes e SÓ EXIBIRÃO as que estiverem de acordo com a resolução atual ou SÓ CARREGARÃO as imagens de acordo com a resolução atual?

Obrigado!

Comment: 2. Sim, eles carregarão. Mas você poderá usar o atributo `srcset` https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Specifications **ou** https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture#Exemplo_1_Uso_com_atributo_media para usar múltiplas resoluções sem o navegador carregar todas as imagens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 -** Se vc estiver usando Bootstrap com o Grid padrão vc teoricamente precisaria das imagens nessas resoluções. Aqui tem a documentação oficial: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
  // Extra small screen / phone
  xs: 0,
  // Small screen / phone
  sm: 576px,
  // Medium screen / tablet
  md: 768px,
  // Large screen / desktop
  lg: 992px,
  // Extra large screen / wide desktop
  xl: 1200px
);
```

**2 -** Para carregar as imagens no slider com cada uma das resoluções do grid vc pode fazer o Srcset como o Valdeir comentou. Dessa forma a sua imagem ficaria com algo parecido com isso:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 576px)" srcset="suaimagem-sm.png" sizes="100vw"/>
    <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="suaimagem-md.png" sizes="100vw"/>
    <source media="(min-width: 992px)" srcset="suaimagem-lg.png" sizes="100vw"/>
    <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="suaimagem-lx.png" sizes="100vw"/>
<picture>
```

Essa resposta tem um teste de carregamento para vc ver como o DevTools do Chrome faz a requisição das imagens no `srcset` [Qual o melhor modo de trabalhar com imagens responsivas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/277651/qual-o-melhor-modo-de-trabalhar-com-imagens-responsivas/277676#277676)

Outra forma de tratar a tag img seria como nesse artigo da Mozilla sobre imagem responsiva https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

```
<img srcset="suaimagem-sm.png 576w,
             suaimagem-md.png 768w,
             suaimagem-lg.png 992w,
             suaimagem-lx.png 1200w"
     sizes="(max-width: 576px) 280px,
            (max-width: 768px) 580px,
            (max-width: 992px) 780px,
            1200px"
       src="suaimagem-lx.png" alt="">
```

Comment: Vi uma tabela do Bootstrap que me mostra as seguintes resoluções: Large Display: 1200px e superior; Default: 980px e superior; Portrait Tablets: 768px e superior; Phones to Tablets: 767px e inferior; Phones: 480px e inferior. Eu deveria cria uma imagem para cada uma dessas categorias de resolução?

Comment: @RogérioLimas se vc quer bem feito tem sim que fazer uma imagem para cada resolução pois cada uma tem um peso diferente quanto menor mais leve. Depois vc tem que usar uma das opções que citei na parte 2 para construir sua tag de imagem ou srcset com o nome de cada imagem de cada resolucao. Vc não precisa fazer isso pro site inteiro, faça apenas no slider e hero images que já eh suficiente se o site for pequeno. Minha opinião ...