# Comportamento tag <img srcset> para utilização de imagens responsivas

Tags: php, html, html5

Olá,

Estou utilizando a tag html `<img srcset = "imagem.jpg, 400w, imagem1.jpg, 300w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 300px,(max-width: 959px) 400px">`

Nos navegadores Edge e Mozilla, funciona perfeitamente, a imagem é selecionada de acordo com a tamanho da tela do navegados.
Mas no chrome (versão 69) e safari não funciona.
Alguém tem já passou por isso, ou que use o a tag html para imagens responsivas pode ajudar?

Comment: Só um detalhe falta fechar as aspas no atributo `srcset`

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset

Comment: @NoobSaibot obrigado!

Comment: @lelopes no site da [*MDN* tem essa nota](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Aprender/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#Ferramentas_de_desenvolvimento_%C3%BAteis): *Use o Mozilla Firefox para testar `srcset`. O Chrome carrega a melhor imagem se estiver em cache no navegador, anulando o propósito do teste na ferramenta de desenvolvimento.*

Comment: @NoobSaibot, ja tinha lido isso. Mas o proposito do srcset é justamente escolher a imagem setada para cada tamanho de tela pela tag. Então no chrome o comportamento é diferente e no safari também. Tive problema com esses dois navegadores. Sabe de alguma outra solução para podermos setar as imagens responsivas para os respectivos tamanhos de tela?

Comment: Eu já usei srcset no chrome e não tive problemas... No meu caso ficava assim: `<img class="d-block w-100" src="img/slider/tintas-sm.jpg" alt="Tintas Líquidas" srcset="img/slider/tintas-sm.jpg 575w,
                         img/slider/tintas-md.jpg 767w,   
                         img/slider/tintas-xl.jpg 768w" sizes="(max-width: 575px) 100vw, 
                        (max-width: 767px) 100vw,
                        768px">` As vezes isso pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/292403/carregamento-das-imagens-em-diferentes-resolu%C3%A7%C3%B5es/292407#292407

Comment: Aqui tb tem um material https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257945/mobile-first-aparecer-imagem-somente-no-desktop/257961#257961

Comment: @hugocsl muito obrigado, vou utilizar seu exemplo.

Comment: Então, é apenas uma sugestão... pode ter gente que pensa diferente e pode sugerir outra opções... eu só indiquei o que funcionou comigo etc. Boa sorte ai tmj